# Error React Native Duplicate Declaration "App"

Tags: react-native, error-handling

I get this error

> "Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios$dev=true&minnify=false)with error;(index.js:/Users/Floyd/sites/crm.node_modules/react-native/index.js"Duplicate declaration"App"[0m[90........

#### `app.js` file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to The CRM!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

#### And `index.js` file

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(crm, () => App);
```

Comment: Which version of `react-native` do you use?

Comment: @ mahdi _italic_ 0.57.2

Answer (score 0):

If you use the lower version, this problem will most likely be solved.

Version `0.55.0` is fine

```
react-native init --version="react-native@0.55.0" YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried but now get this error: Installing Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hello.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Pro Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hello.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Comment: You're welcome. This link can help you for this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308 @FloydOrr-DatetreeDigital